# Why doesn't `tbody` set the background color in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using `<tbody>` as a CSS selector to set the `background-color` in a table.  I'm doing this because I have multiple `<tbody>` sections within the table, and they have different background colors.

My issue is that when using `border-radius` on the cells, the cell doesn't respect the `background-color` of the `tbody`.  That is, the border radius cuts out the corners in the default background color (in this case white), not the tbody color (in this case, green), below.

UPDATE: This problem occurs in Chrome/Safari, but not in Firefox (just tested myself on all 3).  Still looking for a workaround on Chrome (FOUND! See accepted answer).

```css
tr:first-child td:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

table tbody {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><p>TOP LEFT</p></td>
      <td><p>TOP RIGHT</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>BOT LEFT</p></td>
      <td><p>BOT RIGHT</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To be clear, the fix I'm looking for would change the resultant example so it looks like this (I'm just changing the `table tbody` selector to `table` only):

```css
tr:first-child td:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

table { /* changed this line */
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><p>TOP LEFT</p></td>
      <td><p>TOP RIGHT</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>BOT LEFT</p></td>
      <td><p>BOT RIGHT</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I don't want to do it that way, because I want the background-color to be on the `tbody` (which I have multiple ones) NOT on the whole `table`.

Any way to make the tbody color show through?

Comment: To be honest it's not clear to me what expected results are. Explain difference between current snippet and what you want

Comment: I'm on Firefox and the first example is working correctly for me.  The color is on the tbody tag and I can see it.  Are you loading your styles correctly on the page?

Comment: If you run the two code snippets, the output is different - that is, the first one shows a white border at the radius of the red cell, the second example shows a green border.

Comment: I'm on Chrome on Mac OSX

Comment: Would it not be more efficient to not use tbody for setting the background, but assign a class to tr?

Comment: @lvotje50 I can't (or don't know how to) because I want multiple rows with cells with different rowspans to be clumped together.  I use tbody to group the rows I want together.

Comment: Interesting - just installed Firefox, and I see that both code snippets are the same (and the way I want!)  Unfortunately, I need this to be Chrome compatible (Chrome/Safari this is dun broke)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try making the `<tbody>` to render like a block element.

```
tbody {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```css
tr:first-child td:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
tbody {
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><p>TOP LEFT</p></td>
      <td><p>TOP RIGHT</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>BOT LEFT</p></td>
      <td><p>BOT RIGHT</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's likely to be this [chromium bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29427) I think.

Answer (score 4):

An updated answer for other users, if it helps.

On Chrome, the `display: block` fixes the issue.  However, it causes other layout issues with the table, where it does not seem to respect widths.  Using `display: table` instead seems to resolve both issues:

```
tbody {
  background-color: green;
  display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set cellspacing to 0, borders on the table to none, and collapse the table borders (to make sure there is not space around the colored boxes). Then apply the background color to the TD elements instead of the tbody element.