# How do I properly set the background colour of tbody elements in a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, background-color, html-tbody

I have a table consisting of multiple `tbody` elements that consist of multiple `tr` rows:

```
<table>
    <thead>[...]</thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </tbody>

        &c...

</table>
```

When trying to give children `tbody` elements of `table` a background colour (using `table tbody:nth-child(even){}`), only part of the entire `tbody` element is coloured (namely the individual cells). The background colour of the `table` is always partially shining through.

**How can I get an even** `tbody` **field of a single colour, so the different elements can easily be told apart?**

I stumbled upon [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817681/why-doesnt-tbody-set-the-background-color-in-a-table) ([Why doesn't `tbody` set the background color in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817681)) during my search, and the title implicates the exact same problem, but the rest of that question is more specific and actually about getting `border-radius` to cooperate with the set background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the borders of the table element are the culprit here, we need to get rid of those:

- Add `cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'` to your table html code (`<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>`).
- Add `border:none` to your table's CSS.

Now the table should render properly, without any other-coloured lines crossing through, but we might want to reintroduce the spaces surrounding the elements.
The easiest way to achieve this is to give the `td` element some padding (e.g. `table tbody td {padding-top:1em}`). As this won't interfere with the set background colour of the `tbody` elements, this can be used to realign and re-space your table.